# How can I assign a url from a property for a Send Mediator within WSO2 ESB?

Tags: url, wso2, send, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm looking to create a Send Mediator using a url that's configured within a separate database.

I have the url in question assigned to a property `myurl` within my sequence.

How can I create a **send** using this property as the send's url?

Something like ..

```
<property name="myurl" value="http://www.google.com"></property>
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <http method="put" uri-template="{myurl}"></http>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

errors .. (`uri-mapping` and using `get-property('myurl')` etc in the endpoint above has no luck either)

Using the URL ReWriter Mediator didn't help me, as the action doesn't allow an expression, only `value`

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriterule>
    <action value="get-property('myurl')" type="set" fragment="full"></action>
  </rewriterule>
</rewrite>
<send></send>
```

I'm not sure, even if the above worked .. how I'd be able to define it's a `POST` too ..

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `uri.var` prefix for your property names. This [page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/HTTP+Endpoint) has more details on this.

> The URI templates allow a RESTful URI to contain variables that can be populated during mediation runtime using property values whose names have the "uri.var." prefix.

Here is an example from the WSO2 docs of an endpoint that uses property names:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HTTPEndpoint">
    <http uri-template="http://localhost:8080/{uri.var.servicepath}/restapi/{uri.var.servicename}/menu?category={uri.var.category}&amp;type={uri.var.pizzaType}" method="GET"></http>
</endpoint>
```

And the part from the proxy service that calls the endpoint:

```
<inSequence>           
    <property name="uri.var.servicepath" value="PizzaShopServlet"/>
    <property name="uri.var.servicename" value="PizzaWS"/>
    <property name="uri.var.category" value="pizza"/>
    <property name="uri.var.pizzaType" value="pan"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint key="HTTPEndpoint"/>
    </send>
</inSequence>
```

Comment: I was able to create an endpoint with just one parameter.. {uri.var.full} as the uri-template `<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="myEndpoint">
 <http method="{uri.var.method}" uri-template="{uri.var.full}"/>
 </http>
</endpoint>` 
and then call it with
 `<property name="uri.var.full" expression="get-property('myurl')"></property>
<property name="uri.var.method" value="POST"></property>
<send>
  <endpoint key="myEndpoint"></endpoint>
</send>` 
the uri.var.method seemed to work too (editing via the UI replaced the 'method' uri.var.method to a static GET.. can live with that)